# .Net 7 rate limiting - access limiter registered in startup

Tags: .net

I'm currently messing around with [Rate Limiting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/comment-page-2/#comments) added in .Net 7, but cannot find answer for my question in docs or rate limiting announcement.

I want yo use `TokenBucketLimiter` to limit users access to my API. I want to give each user 10 uses and possibility to "pay" for additional uses.

As I understand it can be done by `TryReplenish()` method avalibale in `ReplenishingRateLimiter` - but how can I get reference to my limiter that I've created?

I'm registering it in Startup this like this:

```cs
        services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
        {
            options.GlobalLimiter = PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(resource =>
            {
                var request = resource.Request.Headers["token"].ToString();
                return RateLimitPartition.GetTokenBucketLimiter(request, _ => new TokenBucketRateLimiterOptions
                {
                    TokenLimit = 10,
                    ReplenishmentPeriod = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    TokensPerPeriod = 10,
                    QueueLimit = 0,
                    AutoReplenishment = false,
                });
            });

            options.RejectionStatusCode = 429;
        });
```

Then I want to have some dummy endpoint that allows me to replenish this limiter, something like this:

```cs
    [HttpGet("replenish")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DummyEndpoint()
    {
        var token = Request.Headers["token"].ToString();
        var limiter = //somehow get my limiter based on the token used as partition key;
        limiter.TryReplenish();
        return Ok();
    }
```

Is it possible this way or this has to be done differently and I'm completely missing the point?

Comment: When adding services or options like this they will (usually) be accessible through dependency injection. In your case you will probably be able to access the options by doing `DummyEndpoint([FromServices] IOptions<RateLimiterOptions>)`. Added as comment as I haven't check the implementation.

Comment: @NotFound you're right - I'm able to access RateLimiterOptions this way, but it doesn't help me as I'm not able to get reference to specific Rate Limiter this way due to property containing it being internal :/